# Definition of Conjugacy Class

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

I am reading a note on representation theory; a Dirac Character is defined as:

$$\Omega_{a}=\sum_{g \in \mathcal{C}_{a}} g$$

Then the author argues that $\Omega_{a}$ commutes with all group elements, since $g^{-1} \Omega_{a} g$ simply reorders the elements. This causes confusion...

A conjugacy class is defined as $\left\{f g f^{-1}: f \in G\right\}$ for a fixed $f$, so a Dirac Character should only commute with this particular $f$, but why does it commute with all the group elements?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What is $\mathcal{C}_a$? Some conjugacy class? Maybe you are confused about the definition of a conjugacy class. A conjugacy class is a set of the form $\mathcal{C} = \{ fgf^{-1} : f \in G \}$ for a fixed $g$. We have $x \mathcal{C} x^{-1} = \mathcal{C}$ for all $x \in G$, so $x \Omega_a x^{-1} = \Omega_a$.

Comment: Your *fixed f* should be *fixed g* and the $\Omega_a$ must be interpreted in the group ring of $G$, not in $G$ itself. Also $ \Omega_a$ is not a character but an element of the center of the group ring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By definition, $C_a = \{gag^{-1}:g \in G\}$, so given any $h \in G$,
$$h \Omega_a h^{-1} = \sum_{g \in C_a} hgh^{-1}$$
But $g$ is obtained by conjugating $a$, so $hgh^{-1}$ is also some conjugation of $a$. It is then clear that we are simply permuting the sum, so
$$h \Omega_a h^{-1} = \Omega_a$$